# SyntaxError in asyncToGenerator.js after building and deploying reactjs code on google's app engine

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, google-app-engine, flask, async-await

Upon trying to send login details to the backend, I get this error message in console:
[Uncaught (in) Promise SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0   asyncToGenerator.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ncQt.png)
Please see the image for the error log.

Interestingly, this error occurs even before the fetch statement. The object you see before the error is the result of a console.log() statement just before the fetch call. The object sent that is posted via fetch is constructed as follows:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userObj = {
    method: 'POST',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
  }
 
  const result = await Auth.login(userObj);
  if (result){
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    setAlert(true);
  }
};
```

The function Auth.login() is as follow:

```
const login =async (postObj) => {
  console.log(postObj);
  const response = await fetch('/auth/login', postObj);
  const data = await response.json();
  
  if(data.loggedin){
    Cookies.set('user', data.user);
    Cookies.set('isAuthenticated', true);
  }
  return data.loggedin;
};
```

Sorry for the inconsistency in naming, postObj and userObj are the same. Before deploying everything works, but as soon as I build it and deploy, it shows the SyntaxError in a function which I didn't even write.

The backend funtion at /auth/login is as follows:

```
@app.route('/auth/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
 print("reached /auth/login")
 username = request.json.get('username')
 password = request.json.get('password')
 loggedin=False; userObj = {}

if verify_password(username, password):
    login_user(g.user)
    loggedin =True
    userObj ={"uid":g.user.id, "username": g.user.username, "email": g.user.email}      

return jsonify({"loggedin":loggedin, "user":userObj})
```

Do suggest any solutions, Thank you !

> P.S.
>
> > I have isolated the error using debug statements everywhere. I can tell you with certainity, that this error is occuring even before the frontend manages to reach the /auth/login, backend. The errors occurs just at the fetch, and I am sure it is not even reacing the first line of the function in the backend. I am sure because I dont see that path in the logs nor does the print statement on the first line of the /auth/login function gets printed.

Comment: unexpected token in JSON `<` usually means some request for JSON is getting HTML ... check the developer tools console to see what the server is sending instead of JSON for some request (it'll most likely have 404 status)

Comment: you really should check `if (response.ok)` for your fetch ...

Comment: `fetch` can also return promise rejection on network errors and cancelled requests, which your code doesn't appear to handle well, i.e. the uncaught error you currently have.

Comment: @Jaromanda X, react frontend is not getting through the fetch call. If you check the image for error log, I have printed the post object and it is just a json object. I do not understand how can html be injected somewhere.

Comment: I believe the error is coming from your backend. can you post what's the '/auth/login' is doing?

Comment: `printed the post object and it is just a json object` ... I was talking about the **RESPONSE** ... where I said the *request for JSON is **getting** HTML* ... getting, i.e the **response**

Comment: I have isolated the error using debug statements everywhere. I can tell you with certainity, that this error is occuring even before the frontend manages to react the /auth/login, backend. The errors occurs just at the fetch, and I am sure it is not even reacing the first line of the function in the backend. I am sure because I dont see that path in the logs nor does the print statement on the first line of the /auth/login function gets printed.

Comment: I have posted the /auth/login function.

Comment: ok, just wrap your async call with try and catch and hopefully you won't see the error any  more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 0):

In developmet, setting proxy variable in package.json works but this fails in production. I was not aware of this and hence the above error, the frontend was looking for the path "/auth/login" in its own directory (adding /auth/login to its own url) and that is returning html as the page does not exist. One workaround for this is to use the entire url in the fetch calls or setup .env file which holds environment variables which you can then use in the fetch call.

reference- https://medium.com/better-programming/using-environment-variables-in-reactjs-9ad9c5322408